# iOS app Spotlight search doesn't appears on Applications

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, corespotlight

I need to show my app in spotlight search after searching some keywords. One of this keywords is "booking". Using CoreSpotlight I managed to make it appear on the "app box" itself but not in "Applications" box in results.

As you can see Booking.com, AccorHotels and OpenTable appear on "Applications" box but my app it doesn't. 
What I need to do in order to appear on "Applications" box?
With some of the keywords it appear on the "Top Hit".

[image]

Comment: Does the solution below work for you?

Comment: @Mayank yes, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just discovered that

- Booking.com name on AppStore is "Booking.com Travel Deals"
- OpenTable name on AppStore is "OpenTable Restaurants Booking"
- TripAdvisor name on AppStore is "Tripadvisor Hotels Restaurants"

When searching "booking" on the iPhone, Booking.com and OpenTable appears. Same for searching "Hotels" with TripAdvisor.

So, no code needed. Just change app name on AppStore Connect (this will also improve ASO). 
Remember to set a proper app name in `Bundle name` (info.plist) so users will see the "short name" on the iPhone home screen.

[image]